# SQL SERVER SELECTING ROW

Tags: sql, sql-server

If  I have this table below

```
   id         time
   start      08.00 AM 
   stop       09.00 AM
   stop       09.30 AM
   start      09.30 AM
   start      11.00 AM
   start      11.30 AM
   stop       11.40 AM
   stop       12.00 PM
```

I want output that only take every **first start** and **every start after stop** and **the latest stop**

Any solution?

This is how the output I want:

```
   id         time
   start      08.00 AM 
   stop       09.00 AM
   start      09.30 AM
   stop       11.40 AM
   stop       12.00 PM
```

Comment: I totally newbie about this thing, that's why i have no idea what I suppose to do. Please give some suggestions.

Comment: Please give some solutions

Comment: from that table, are there no other columns like identifier id?

Comment: the identifier id only start and stop, it has been convert from 0 == stop and 1 == start

Comment: from what I can see, the values in ID is not supposed to be an id. Design wise you already have an issue.

Comment: if I change ID into status, how i can make output like I want? I have machine that stored data like table I post, I want to convert it like table output I post either.

Comment: or if I have input like my table, how i can design it wise?

Comment: How can you be sure that `stop, 09.30 AM` comes before `start, 09.30 AM` and not the other way around? Same goes about `start, 11.30 AM` and `stop, 11.30 AM`. There's nothing (at least, you've disclosed nothing) that suggests the particular order in which the rows should be interpreted.

Comment: Design it like id=1 status='start' time='9:00 AM' id=2 status='stop' time='9:30 AM' and etc... so we will know which row entry comes first.

Comment: by the way is this an assignment?

Comment: why need stop on last row in result?

Comment: I'm sorry for:  start, 11.30 AM and stop, 11.30 AM it's wrong. but for stop, 09.30 AM comes before start, 09.30 AM. I mean the end of machine status stop is 09.30 AM and it change to machine status 09.30 is start

Comment: I can change id into row number but what i want based on the machine status to take the actual time, not based on id number or something like that

Comment: I need stop on last row because if the job of machine done it means totally stop not just some break.

Comment: The times *will* be taken into account. The ids (or whatever) are only needed as a tie-breaker, to resolve the situations where `stop` and `start` occur at *exactly* the same time. It doesn't have to be an additional column, actually. Maybe there's a rule that if the two distinct events coincide, one must always be considered before the other? Like `start` before `stop`, perhaps?

Comment: **stop always before start** because the machine *first status always stop and then start*, i'm just not write it on my post.

Comment: Please *do* write it then. :) That's an important part of the question.

Comment: Ah, that's why the first status is start in this example...

Comment: @Jacco, this is look like I want http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97181/1 but could you please make it with time interval column please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT id AS pr, [time], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [time]) AS Id,
         COUNT(*) OVER() AS cnt        
  FROM dbo.test21 t1
  ), cte2 AS
 (
  SELECT Id, pr, [time], pr AS prStart, [time] AS StopTime, pr AS prStop, [time] AS StartTime
  FROM cte
  WHERE Id = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c1.Id, 
         CASE WHEN c1.pr != c2.pr OR c1.Id = c1.cnt THEN c1.pr ELSE c2.pr END,
         CASE WHEN c1.pr != c2.pr OR c1.Id = c1.cnt THEN c1.[time] ELSE c2.[time] END,
         c1.pr, c1.[time], c2.pr, c2.[time]
  FROM cte c1 JOIN cte2 c2 ON c1.Id = c2.Id + 1
  )
  SELECT pr, [time], MIN(StartTime) AS StartTime,
         MAX(DATEDIFF(minute, StartTime, [time])) AS Interval
  FROM cte2
  GROUP BY pr, [time]
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f951f/2/0)

Comment: Could you please add some interval time column? So it will look like what Jacco below post. PLease.

Comment: thank you your post is exactly what I want

Comment: I'm sorry could you please make **time interval column** that look like this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0079a/7

Comment: Why the first stop not until 09.30 ?

Comment: Added time interval column. Try

Comment: Why the first stop not until 09.30 but 09.00? Your answer are the best, I hope you could continue answer my questions.

Comment: it is written in your expected results.

Comment: .What do you think about this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582242/sql-selecting-row

Answer (score 4):

Whitout having any primary key or some different id for each row... the only solution that comes in my mind is something like:

```
select rn, id , time
from
(select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by time) as rn, id, time from test 
where id = 'start'
union
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by time) as rn, id, time from test 
where id = 'stop'
) d
order by rn
```

Basically i made an union between the started and the stopped rows like this:

```
 (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by time) as rn, id, time from test 
    where id = 'start'
    union
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by time) as rn, id, time from test 
    where id = 'stop'
    ) d
```

returns:

```
    1   start   08.00
    2   start   11.00
    3   start   12.00
    4   start   13.00
    1   stop    09.00
    2   stop    10.00
    3   stop    14.00
    4   stop    15.00
```

From original input:

```
id          time
start   08.00
stop    09.00
stop    10.00
start   11.00
start   12.00
start   13.00
stop    14.00
stop    15.00
```

Now you only have to order them by they own row number... that is that rn.

And at the end you will have:

```
1   start   08.00
1   stop    09.00
2   start   11.00
2   stop    10.00
3   start   12.00
3   stop    14.00
4   start   13.00
4   stop    15.00
```

@Note: my example values are close to yours... but fictive...

Comment: Could you please explain it? I'm sorry I just newbie. Thanks

Comment: There isn't too much to explain... i just used the ROW_NUMBER() function to create some sort of id... so i can arrange those rows

Comment: Could you please show me your table before it processed? Please see my post on top, I think this is not output that I want.

Comment: how to order them by they own row number? I'm sorry again i'm just newbie

Comment: Don't you think that row number 2 is confusing, it start at 11.00 and stop at 10.00 ?

Answer (score 2):

I have some alternative, that will give the results in a different format. But it does return the information requested.

```
SELECT
  MIN([main].[Start]) AS [Start],
  [main].[End] AS [Stop],
  DATEDIFF(minute, MIN([main].[Start]), [main].[End]) AS [Minutes]
FROM
(
  SELECT
    [sub].[Start],
    MIN([sub].[End]) AS [End]
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      [start].[time] AS [Start],
      [start].[id] AS [StartingStatus],
      [end].[time] AS [End],
      [end].[id] AS [EndingStatus]
    FROM [Log] [start],  [Log] [end]
    WHERE [start].[id] = 'start' 
      AND [start].[time] < [end].[time]
      AND [start].[id] <> [end].[id]
  ) AS [sub]
  GROUP BY
    [sub].[Start],
    [sub].[StartingStatus]
) AS [main]
GROUP BY
  [main].[End]
```

Basically, it first selects all records `where [id] = 'start'`. Then it finds all records with a later time and `where [id] <> 'start'`.

On these records, it groups by each 'start' and determines the first 'stop'-time. Then these records are grouped again, to find the first 'start'-time for each 'stop'-time.

The results look like this:

```
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+
| START                          | STOP                           | MINUTES |
+================================+================================+=========+
| January, 29 2013 08:00:00+0000 | January, 29 2013 09:00:00+0000 | 60      |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+
| January, 29 2013 09:30:00+0000 | January, 29 2013 11:30:00+0000 | 120     |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+
| January, 29 2013 11:30:00+0000 | January, 29 2013 12:00:00+0000 | 30      |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+
```

The Fiddle is found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0079a/7).

*PS: This answer is base on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14512010/410699).*

Comment: the first stop time should be 90 minutes or until 09.30. Could you please change your code so it gives result like I want? thank you

Comment: @user2020598: According to your example, the first stop after `8:00` is at `9:00`. Why do you want to it to be `9:30`? Also, you never said you wanted the results like this. It's just Jacco's suggestion that you might find this kind of output more convenient. If you like it this way, please accept this answer and ask a *new* question about how to change it so it displays a different end time. I'm talking about a new question because many people have already contributed to solving your original question, so it would be infair to *edit* it only to accommodate for this kind of output.

Comment: I'm sorry what I want is time before **next start time** or **the last stop time** before **next start**

Comment: I agree with @AndriyM and I'm lost at what the OP exactly wants at this point.

Comment: No no no, I'm not lost! I totally understand, since my answer is accepted!

Comment: At this point, I can only contribute my +1.

Comment: @Jacco, this is look like I want sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97181/1 but could you please make it with time interval column please?

Comment: Ah, NO! It's not accepted, I'm lost again! @user2020598 please create a new question for this. Just because I have the minutes in my answer, it is outside of the (original) scope of your question.

Comment: What do you think about this problem stackoverflow.com/questions/14582242/sql-selecting-row

Answer (score 1):

After clarifications made in the comments, this turns out a classic [gaps-n-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-n-islands) problem.

Assuming this is SQL Server 2005+, you could use the following method:

```
WITH partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    grp = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time, CASE id WHEN 'stop' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time)
  FROM atable
)
SELECT
  id,
  time = MIN(time)
FROM partitioned
GROUP BY
  id,
  grp
ORDER BY
  time
;
```

Comment: Could you please show me on at sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @user2020598: Could you not just apply it to your data? On the other hand, you could also prepare a data sample at SQL Fiddle for me, then I would adjust this script to your data sample.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a268a/1

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97181/1

Comment: @user2020598: Thanks for permitting me to use other people's Fiddles. :) All right, here you go: [#1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a268a/2), [#2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97181/2). You don't really like doing your own homework, do you. :)

Comment: my deadline just crazzzzy.., Why the first stop not until 09.30 ?

Comment: This query produces almost exactly the same output as in your question. The only difference is the last row. This query doesn't return it, because it is a `stop` row that follows another `stop` row, while you seem to want `stop` rows to follow `start` rows and vice versa. And it doesn't seem to make sense too to show two sequential `stop` events. I mean, if there was a stop at some point, what difference would it make to indicate that there was another stop after that and but there was no start in-between?