# SQL SELECTING ROW

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL SERVER SELECTING ROW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577406/sql-server-selecting-row)

If  I have this table below

```
   id         time
   start      08.00 AM 
   stop       09.00 AM
   stop       09.30 AM
   start      09.30 AM
   start      11.00 AM
   start      11.30 AM
   stop       11.30 AM
   stop       12.00 PM
```

I want output that looks like output below:

Any solution?

This is how the output I want:

```
    id         time       end_time    interval 
   start      08.00 AM    09.00 AM      60 minute
   stop       09.00 AM    09.30 AM      30 minute
   start      09.30 AM    11.30 AM      120 minute
   stop       11.30 AM    12.00 PM      30 minute
   stop       12.00 PM     NULL          NULL
```

Comment: A column with name `id` and a value of `start/stop`? What type is `time`?

Comment: [Looks almost identical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577406/sql-server-selecting-row).

Comment: Didn't [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14579032/1369235) help you?

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter , time is TIME/DATE type, it looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577406/sql-server-selecting-row#comment20352142_14579032), but with output like those on top

Comment: @Dukeling , yes its identical but with different output. <br/>

Comment: @hims056 , it's just different output with a little bit different problem

Comment: @user2020598: `DATE` is a type, `TIME` is a different and a third is `DATETIME`, what type are you using? Btw, what have you tried? Seems as if you would just ask for code.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f951f , but its not output that i want

Comment: I'm voting to reopen on the same grounds as I laid out [when suggesting to post this new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577406/sql-server-selecting-row/14579166#comment20347564_14578968). The previous one had gathered several answers before the OP decided they wanted differently formatted output. Editing the previous question would essentially devoid the answers posted by that time.

Comment: You should really try and lay out the business rules governing this process in as much depth as you can so that the best solution can be provided. Don't just say "I gave the output I need" but maybe an explanation of why certain rows are skipped? This reeks of "incomplete data" but we can't know that.

Answer (score 0):

> I want output that only take every first start and every start after
>   stop and the latest stop

That's easily done with the `row_number()` window function:

```
; with  numbered as
        (
        select  row_number() over (order by [time]) rn
        ,       count(*) over() as cnt
        ,       *
        from    Table1
        )
select  *
from    numbered cur
left join
        numbered prev
on      cur.rn = prev.rn + 1
left join
        numbered next
on      cur.rn = next.rn - 1
where   cur.rn in (1, cur.cnt) -- first or last row
        or (cur.id = 'start' and prev.id = 'stop') -- start after stop
order by
        cur.rn
```

[Live example on SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0df14/9/0)

Not that your example output does not meet your requirements.  It includes several rows that match neither of the three criteria (first row, last row, start after stop.)

Comment: i'm sorry my mistake, please see my post again